# Zookeeper: Get Leader node from Follower node

Tags: apache-zookeeper, quorum, ensembles

If I have an ensemble of Zookeeper nodes where I have the IP of one of the Zookeeper node which is a 'follower' node, is it possible to find out the 'Leader' node from the follower node by connecting through zkCli or Curator client  ?